# Apache Beam Issue with Spark Runner while using Kafka IO

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I am trying to test KafkaIO for the Apache Beam Code with a Spark Runner.
The code works fine with a Direct Runner.

However, if I add below codeline it throws error:

```
options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3307)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2135)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

*Versions that I am trying to use:*

```
<beam.version>2.33.0</beam.version>
<spark.version>3.1.2</spark.version>
<kafka.version>3.0.0</kafka.version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by adding VM argument: -Xss2M

This link helped me to solve this issue:
https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/10370